# Proof using Fubini

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-writing

Suppose $f:\left[0,1\right] \times \left[0,1\right] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable.

How does one prove that
$$\int^1_0\left(\int^x_0f(x,y)dy\right)dx = \int^1_0\left(\int^1_yf(x,y)dx\right)dy?$$

To me it seems as  quite straightforward application of Fubini, but I can't seem to prove it correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a function $ g:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $ defined as follows : $$ g:\left(x,y\right)\mapsto\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}0,\ \ \ \ \text{If }\ x< y\leq 1\\ f\left(x,y\right),\ \ \ \ \text{If }\  0\leq y \leq x\end{aligned}\right. $$

Then : $$ \small\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{0}^{x}{f\left(x,y\right)\mathrm{d}y}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{0}^{1}{g\left(x,y\right)\mathrm{d}y}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{0}^{1}{g\left(x,y\right)\mathrm{d}x}\,\mathrm{d}y}=\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{y}^{1}{f\left(x,y\right)\mathrm{d}x}\,\mathrm{d}y} $$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\int^1_0\left(\int^x_0f(x,y)dy\right)dx &=\int^1_0\left(\int^1_0 1\{y\le x\}f(x,y)dy\right)dx \\
&=\int^1_0\left(\int^1_0 1\{y\le x\}f(x,y)dx\right)dy \\
&= \int^1_0\left(\int^1_yf(x,y)dx\right)dy.
\end{align}

Comment: so basically you used fubini in the second equation?

Comment: @Geigercounter That's right.